# Open and Save Word files through internet

Tags: file, ms-word, save

I have a situation that override my knowledge. Here is situation:
A simple web based system store a Word files. Users create them locally, then upload them to server. After that, another user can download, edit and upload again. All that is okay, but that steps of repeating Download/Upload cause troubles - in case when user forgot to upload after he make changes. The prerequisites is that they want to use only Word, so i can't use any web editors like CKEditor or Google Documents.

So - a question - is there a way to let users open/save that DOC files with Word without setting a VPN?

Server is a Windows 2008, and language is ASP.NET / classicASP. User access system via browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can embed a plugin called aceoffix in your web system, if the customers do not have to download, upload and save back to server. With aceoffix they can edit online and save back to the server directly. It is exactly the same interface as MS Office. Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think an embedded Word viewer would be something quite complex to pull off - especially if they require the native, proper and exact Word look/menus.

One alternative is to provide a plugin to your users, where they can access/sync documents directly from/to the server. But then you aren't using the a web site but a local plugin, which comes with its own headaches of course.

Creating a Word plugin is a nice way to make it seem like something "in the Office program" when you have actually created it yourself, so that your user don't have to feel like they are using another program. My idea is that you could create a way for users to load a Word file from the server, do changes to it and then upload them back to the server automatically.

Comment: Hi Anders. I can't understand clearly - that word viewer you talk about - are Save function present? But Save on server, not locally. I found a lot of word viewers, also the Word himself can be embedded in browser, can load file from server, but cant's save it remotely.

Comment: Ugh - sorry, I DO think it would be hard to pull it off. Typo. :/

Comment: Exactly - upload back to server automatically is my milestone. Thank you and no problem. It seems that i must write some little tool to make that...

Answer (score 0):

How about a tiny app (on clients) to act as a syncronizer (using FTP) ?

Comment: Hi Jorge. I was thinking just for something like that, but can't find anything useful via Google :( Maybe i'm wrong somewhere. Can you post me a link to that tiny app which can be used as a FTP synchronizer? If that app support a command line options or something like that, maybe i can use it.

Comment: @xentia I was sugesting you to make your own. Its not hard. Get started... and then, we are here to help :)

Comment: Thank you Jorge. This may be a solution in the last resort. The problem is that some of users are very very suspicious. They don't wont any software different from MS Office and Browser :( Anyway, if that is the way :) - i'll ask again if needed.